# How can I resurrect a branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase, remote-branch

I have a refactoring/cleanup branch `cleanup` where I clean up technical debt. After going through one cycle, I merge this branch back into `master`.

A few weeks later, I have the time to clean up some more and I wanted to resurrect the branch instead of creating a new one. So I pulled `master` and then moved the local branch pointer for `cleanup` to `HEAD`:

```
> git show HEAD
commit dd61...
> git branch -f cleanup dd61...
> git checkout cleanup
```

After this, I could pull and push and the history looked correct. But I had some subtle problems when trying to pull in the latest changes and do a rebase. My usual workflow to rebase the current branch is:

```
> git pull origin master
> git rebase master
```

But when I do it with the resurrected branch, then the `git pull` will already start a merge or maybe even a rebase even though I didn't specify `--rebase`.

My guess is that I should have moved the remote branch pointer as well. I did push `cleanup` after the `checkout` above but maybe that wasn't enough?

Can someone explain what is going on in my situation and how I can resurrect a shared (= was pushed to `origin`) branch correctly?

Answer (score 1):

After you moved pointer to `dd61` you should do `push origin cleanup --force` to move it on `origin`

Comment: Can I still do it after pulling/pushing `cleanup` several times or this this branch now "broken" and I should delete it?